# Ubuntu 12.04 : Not all updates can be installed

Tags: updates, update-manager

I have ubuntu 12.04 installed on my machine.When I run the update manager on my machine I get the following message.[image]

I don't know how to fix this issue.Is it safe to run apt-get dist upgrade.? I am quite happy with Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and not keen on moving to a newer release.Please advice.

Output of

sudo apt-get update

on command line is given below.

```
Hit http://mirror.aarnet.edu.au precise Release.gpg
Hit http://mirror.aarnet.edu.au precise-updates Release.gpg
Hit http://mirror.aarnet.edu.au precise-backports Release.gpg
Hit http://mirror.aarnet.edu.au precise-security Release.gpg
Hit http://mirror.aarnet.edu.au precise Release
Hit http://mirror.aarnet.edu.au precise-updates Release
Hit http://mirror.aarnet.edu.au precise-backports Release
Hit http://mirror.aarnet.edu.au precise-security Release
Hit http://mirror.aarnet.edu.au precise/main Sources
Hit http://mirror.aarnet.edu.au precise/restricted Sources
Hit http://mirror.aarnet.edu.au precise/universe Sources
Hit http://mirror.aarnet.edu.au precise/multiverse Sources
Hit http://mirror.aarnet.edu.au precise/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://mirror.aarnet.edu.au precise/restricted amd64 Packages
Hit http://mirror.aarnet.edu.au precise/universe amd64 Packages
Hit http://mirror.aarnet.edu.au precise/multiverse amd64 Packages
Hit http://mirror.aarnet.edu.au precise/main i386 Packages
Hit http://mirror.aarnet.edu.au precise/restricted i386 Packages
Hit http://www.scootersoftware.com stable Release.gpg
Hit http://mirror.aarnet.edu.au precise/universe i386 Packages
Hit http://mirror.aarnet.edu.au precise/multiverse i386 Packages
Hit http://mirror.aarnet.edu.au precise/main TranslationIndex
Hit http://mirror.aarnet.edu.au precise/multiverse TranslationIndex
Hit http://mirror.aarnet.edu.au precise/restricted TranslationIndex
Hit http://mirror.aarnet.edu.au precise/universe TranslationIndex
Hit http://mirror.aarnet.edu.au precise-updates/main Sources
Hit http://mirror.aarnet.edu.au precise-updates/restricted Sources
Hit http://mirror.aarnet.edu.au precise-updates/universe Sources
Hit http://download.virtualbox.org precise Release.gpg
Hit http://mirror.aarnet.edu.au precise-updates/multiverse Sources
Hit http://mirror.aarnet.edu.au precise-updates/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://mirror.aarnet.edu.au precise-updates/restricted amd64 Packages
Hit http://mirror.aarnet.edu.au precise-updates/universe amd64 Packages
Hit http://mirror.aarnet.edu.au precise-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages
Hit http://mirror.aarnet.edu.au precise-updates/main i386 Packages
Hit http://mirror.aarnet.edu.au precise-updates/restricted i386 Packages
Hit http://mirror.aarnet.edu.au precise-updates/universe i386 Packages
Hit http://mirror.aarnet.edu.au precise-updates/multiverse i386 Packages
Hit http://mirror.aarnet.edu.au precise-updates/main TranslationIndex
Hit http://mirror.aarnet.edu.au precise-updates/multiverse TranslationIndex
Hit http://mirror.aarnet.edu.au precise-updates/restricted TranslationIndex
Hit http://mirror.aarnet.edu.au precise-updates/universe TranslationIndex
Hit http://mirror.aarnet.edu.au precise-backports/main Sources
Hit http://mirror.aarnet.edu.au precise-backports/restricted Sources
Hit http://mirror.aarnet.edu.au precise-backports/universe Sources
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com precise Release.gpg
Hit http://archive.canonical.com precise Release.gpg
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise Release.gpg
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise Release.gpg
Hit http://mirror.aarnet.edu.au precise-backports/multiverse Sources
Hit http://mirror.aarnet.edu.au precise-backports/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://mirror.aarnet.edu.au precise-backports/restricted amd64 Packages
Hit http://mirror.aarnet.edu.au precise-backports/universe amd64 Packages
Hit http://mirror.aarnet.edu.au precise-backports/multiverse amd64 Packages
Hit http://mirror.aarnet.edu.au precise-backports/main i386 Packages
Hit http://mirror.aarnet.edu.au precise-backports/restricted i386 Packages
Hit http://mirror.aarnet.edu.au precise-backports/universe i386 Packages
Hit http://mirror.aarnet.edu.au precise-backports/multiverse i386 Packages
Hit http://mirror.aarnet.edu.au precise-backports/main TranslationIndex
Hit http://mirror.aarnet.edu.au precise-backports/multiverse TranslationIndex
Hit http://download.virtualbox.org precise Release
Hit http://mirror.aarnet.edu.au precise-backports/restricted TranslationIndex
Hit http://mirror.aarnet.edu.au precise-backports/universe TranslationIndex
Hit http://mirror.aarnet.edu.au precise-security/main Sources
Hit http://mirror.aarnet.edu.au precise-security/restricted Sources
Hit http://mirror.aarnet.edu.au precise-security/universe Sources
Hit http://mirror.aarnet.edu.au precise-security/multiverse Sources
Hit http://mirror.aarnet.edu.au precise-security/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://mirror.aarnet.edu.au precise-security/restricted amd64 Packages
Hit http://mirror.aarnet.edu.au precise-security/universe amd64 Packages
Hit http://mirror.aarnet.edu.au precise-security/multiverse amd64 Packages
Hit http://mirror.aarnet.edu.au precise-security/main i386 Packages
Hit http://mirror.aarnet.edu.au precise-security/restricted i386 Packages
Hit http://mirror.aarnet.edu.au precise-security/universe i386 Packages
Hit http://mirror.aarnet.edu.au precise-security/multiverse i386 Packages
Hit http://mirror.aarnet.edu.au precise-security/main TranslationIndex
Hit http://mirror.aarnet.edu.au precise-security/multiverse TranslationIndex
Hit http://mirror.aarnet.edu.au precise-security/restricted TranslationIndex
Hit http://mirror.aarnet.edu.au precise-security/universe TranslationIndex
Hit http://mirror.aarnet.edu.au precise/main Translation-en
Hit http://mirror.aarnet.edu.au precise/multiverse Translation-en
Hit http://www.scootersoftware.com stable Release
Hit http://mirror.aarnet.edu.au precise/restricted Translation-en
Hit http://mirror.aarnet.edu.au precise/universe Translation-en
Hit http://dl.google.com stable Release.gpg
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com precise Release
Hit http://archive.canonical.com precise Release
Hit http://mirror.aarnet.edu.au precise-updates/main Translation-en
Hit http://mirror.aarnet.edu.au precise-updates/multiverse Translation-en
Hit http://mirror.aarnet.edu.au precise-updates/restricted Translation-en
Hit http://mirror.aarnet.edu.au precise-updates/universe Translation-en
Hit http://mirror.aarnet.edu.au precise-backports/main Translation-en
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise Release
Hit http://mirror.aarnet.edu.au precise-backports/multiverse Translation-en
Hit http://mirror.aarnet.edu.au precise-backports/restricted Translation-en
Hit http://mirror.aarnet.edu.au precise-backports/universe Translation-en
Hit http://mirror.aarnet.edu.au precise-security/main Translation-en
Hit http://download.virtualbox.org precise/contrib amd64 Packages
Hit http://mirror.aarnet.edu.au precise-security/multiverse Translation-en
Hit http://mirror.aarnet.edu.au precise-security/restricted Translation-en
Hit http://mirror.aarnet.edu.au precise-security/universe Translation-en
Hit http://dl.google.com stable Release
Hit http://download.virtualbox.org precise/contrib i386 Packages
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com precise/main Sources
Hit http://archive.canonical.com precise/partner Sources
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise Release
Hit http://www.scootersoftware.com stable/non-free amd64 Packages
Hit http://dl.google.com stable/main amd64 Packages
Ign http://download.virtualbox.org precise/contrib TranslationIndex
Hit http://dl.google.com stable/main i386 Packages
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com precise/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com precise/main i386 Packages
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com precise/main TranslationIndex
Hit http://archive.canonical.com precise/partner amd64 Packages
Hit http://archive.canonical.com precise/partner i386 Packages
Ign http://archive.canonical.com precise/partner TranslationIndex
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Sources
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main i386 Packages
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main TranslationIndex
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main TranslationIndex
Hit http://www.scootersoftware.com stable/non-free i386 Packages
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Sources
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main i386 Packages
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main TranslationIndex
Ign http://www.scootersoftware.com stable/non-free TranslationIndex
Ign http://download.virtualbox.org precise/contrib Translation-en_NZ
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en_NZ
Ign http://download.virtualbox.org precise/contrib Translation-en
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com precise/main Translation-en_NZ
Ign http://archive.canonical.com precise/partner Translation-en_NZ
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com precise/main Translation-en
Ign http://archive.canonical.com precise/partner Translation-en
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-en_NZ
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-en
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-en_NZ
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-en
Ign http://www.scootersoftware.com stable/non-free Translation-en_NZ
Ign http://www.scootersoftware.com stable/non-free Translation-en
Reading package lists...
```

output of `sudo apt-get upgrade`

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  libexttextcat-data libreoffice-base-core libreoffice-calc libreoffice-common libreoffice-core libreoffice-draw libreoffice-emailmerge libreoffice-gnome
  libreoffice-gtk libreoffice-help-en-us libreoffice-impress libreoffice-math libreoffice-style-tango libreoffice-writer linux-generic linux-headers-generic
  linux-image-generic mysql-client-5.5 mysql-server-5.5 mysql-server-core-5.5 python-uno uno-libs3 ure
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 23 not upgraded.
```

output of `cat /var/log/apt/history.log`

```
Start-Date: 2013-08-13  17:25:02
Commandline: apt-get install colordiff
Install: colordiff:amd64 (1.0.9-1)
End-Date: 2013-08-13  17:25:09

Start-Date: 2013-08-14  08:18:29
Commandline: aptdaemon role='role-commit-packages' sender=':1.66'
Upgrade: apt-transport-https:amd64 (0.8.16~exp12ubuntu10.10, 0.8.16~exp12ubuntu10.12), unity:amd64 (5.18.0-0ubuntu2, 5.20.0-0ubuntu2), gir1.2-dbusmenu-gtk-0.4:amd64 (0.6.2-0ubuntu0.1, 0.6.2-0ubuntu0.2), libebackend-1.2-1:amd64 (3.2.3-0ubuntu7, 3.2.3-0ubuntu7.1), bind9-host:amd64 (9.8.1.dfsg.P1-4ubuntu0.6, 9.8.1.dfsg.P1-4ubuntu0.7), gwibber-service-identica:amd64 (3.4.2-0ubuntu2.2, 3.4.2-0ubuntu2.3), libgudev-1.0-0:amd64 (175-0ubuntu9.3, 175-0ubuntu9.4), libgudev-1.0-0:i386 (175-0ubuntu9.3, 175-0ubuntu9.4), thunderbird-locale-en-us:amd64 (17.0.7+build1-0ubuntu0.12.04.1, 17.0.8+build1-0ubuntu0.12.04.1), libxml2-utils:amd64 (2.7.8.dfsg-5.1ubuntu4.4, 2.7.8.dfsg-5.1ubuntu4.6), dnsutils:amd64 (9.8.1.dfsg.P1-4ubuntu0.6, 9.8.1.dfsg.P1-4ubuntu0.7), mysql-server:amd64 (5.5.31-0ubuntu0.12.04.2, 5.5.32-0ubuntu0.12.04.1), fonts-opensymbol:amd64 (102.2+LibO4.0.4~rc2-0ubuntu1~precise1, 102.3+LibO4.1.0-0ubuntu1~precise1~ppa1), libevince3-3:amd64 (3.4.0-0ubuntu1.6, 3.4.0-0ubuntu1.7), thunderbird:amd64 (17.0.7+build1-0ubuntu0.12.04.1, 17.0.8+build1-0ubuntu0.12.04.1), gir1.2-dbusmenu-glib-0.4:amd64 (0.6.2-0ubuntu0.1, 0.6.2-0ubuntu0.2), liblcms2-2:amd64 (2.4-0ubuntu1~precise1, 2.5-0ubuntu1~precise1), unity-common:amd64 (5.18.0-0ubuntu2, 5.20.0-0ubuntu2), lightdm:amd64 (1.2.3-0ubuntu2.2, 1.2.3-0ubuntu2.3), firefox-globalmenu:amd64 (22.0+build2-0ubuntu0.12.04.2, 23.0+build2-0ubuntu0.12.04.1), libdns81:amd64 (9.8.1.dfsg.P1-4ubuntu0.6, 9.8.1.dfsg.P1-4ubuntu0.7), gwibber-service-twitter:amd64 (3.4.2-0ubuntu2.2, 3.4.2-0ubuntu2.3), gwibber-service-facebook:amd64 (3.4.2-0ubuntu2.2, 3.4.2-0ubuntu2.3), libwps-0.2-2:amd64 (0.2.7-1~precise1, 0.2.9-1ubuntu1~precise1), libapt-inst1.4:amd64 (0.8.16~exp12ubuntu10.10, 0.8.16~exp12ubuntu10.12), apport:amd64 (2.0.1-0ubuntu17.3, 2.0.1-0ubuntu17.4), libedata-book-1.2-11:amd64 (3.2.3-0ubuntu7, 3.2.3-0ubuntu7.1), grub-pc:amd64 (1.99-21ubuntu3.9, 1.99-21ubuntu3.10), libmysqlclient18:amd64 (5.5.31-0ubuntu0.12.04.2, 5.5.32-0ubuntu0.12.04.1), libisccc80:amd64 (9.8.1.dfsg.P1-4ubuntu0.6, 9.8.1.dfsg.P1-4ubuntu0.7), apt-utils:amd64 (0.8.16~exp12ubuntu10.10, 0.8.16~exp12ubuntu10.12), libedata-cal-1.2-13:amd64 (3.2.3-0ubuntu7, 3.2.3-0ubuntu7.1), skype:amd64 (4.2.0.11-0ubuntu0.12.04.1, 4.2.0.11-0ubuntu0.12.04.2), linux-firmware:amd64 (1.79.4, 1.79.6), libvlc5:amd64 (2.0.5-0ubuntu0.12.04.1, 2.0.8-0ubuntu0.12.04.1), udev:amd64 (175-0ubuntu9.3, 175-0ubuntu9.4), apt:amd64 (0.8.16~exp12ubuntu10.10, 0.8.16~exp12ubuntu10.12), firefox:amd64 (22.0+build2-0ubuntu0.12.04.2, 23.0+build2-0ubuntu0.12.04.1), unity-lens-files:amd64 (5.10.0-0ubuntu1, 5.10.0-0ubuntu1.1), liblwres80:amd64 (9.8.1.dfsg.P1-4ubuntu0.6, 9.8.1.dfsg.P1-4ubuntu0.7), vlc-nox:amd64 (2.0.5-0ubuntu0.12.04.1, 2.0.8-0ubuntu0.12.04.1), libdbusmenu-glib4:amd64 (0.6.2-0ubuntu0.1, 0.6.2-0ubuntu0.2), vlc-plugin-notify:amd64 (2.0.5-0ubuntu0.12.04.1, 2.0.8-0ubuntu0.12.04.1), mysql-client-core-5.5:amd64 (5.5.31-0ubuntu0.12.04.2, 5.5.32-0ubuntu0.12.04.1), libgwibber2:amd64 (3.4.2-0ubuntu2.2, 3.4.2-0ubuntu2.3), python-problem-report:amd64 (2.0.1-0ubuntu17.3, 2.0.1-0ubuntu17.4), libunity-core-5.0-5:amd64 (5.18.0-0ubuntu2, 5.20.0-0ubuntu2), libcroco3:amd64 (0.6.5-1, 0.6.5-1ubuntu0.1), libcroco3:i386 (0.6.5-1, 0.6.5-1ubuntu0.1), libwpd-0.9-9:amd64 (0.9.6-2~precise1, 0.9.8-1~precise1), libedataserver-1.2-15:amd64 (3.2.3-0ubuntu7, 3.2.3-0ubuntu7.1), libdbusmenu-gtk4:amd64 (0.6.2-0ubuntu0.1, 0.6.2-0ubuntu0.2), libdbusmenu-gtk3-4:amd64 (0.6.2-0ubuntu0.1, 0.6.2-0ubuntu0.2), libebook-1.2-12:amd64 (3.2.3-0ubuntu7, 3.2.3-0ubuntu7.1), evince-common:amd64 (3.4.0-0ubuntu1.6, 3.4.0-0ubuntu1.7), libgcrypt11:amd64 (1.5.0-3ubuntu0.1, 1.5.0-3ubuntu0.2), libgcrypt11:i386 (1.5.0-3ubuntu0.1, 1.5.0-3ubuntu0.2), libxml2:amd64 (2.7.8.dfsg-5.1ubuntu4.4, 2.7.8.dfsg-5.1ubuntu4.6), libxml2:i386 (2.7.8.dfsg-5.1ubuntu4.4, 2.7.8.dfsg-5.1ubuntu4.6), libbind9-80:amd64 (9.8.1.dfsg.P1-4ubuntu0.6, 9.8.1.dfsg.P1-4ubuntu0.7), google-chrome-stable:amd64 (28.0.1500.71-r209842, 28.0.1500.95-r213514), evince:amd64 (3.4.0-0ubuntu1.6, 3.4.0-0ubuntu1.7), libapt-pkg4.12:amd64 (0.8.16~exp12ubuntu10.10, 0.8.16~exp12ubuntu10.12), libcamel-1.2-29:amd64 (3.2.3-0ubuntu7, 3.2.3-0ubuntu7.1), libxml2-dev:amd64 (2.7.8.dfsg-5.1ubuntu4.4, 2.7.8.dfsg-5.1ubuntu4.6), firefox-locale-en:amd64 (22.0+build2-0ubuntu0.12.04.2, 23.0+build2-0ubuntu0.12.04.1), libecal-1.2-10:amd64 (3.2.3-0ubuntu7, 3.2.3-0ubuntu7.1), lsb-base:amd64 (4.0-0ubuntu20.2, 4.0-0ubuntu20.3), unity-services:amd64 (5.18.0-0ubuntu2, 5.20.0-0ubuntu2), gwibber-service:amd64 (3.4.2-0ubuntu2.2, 3.4.2-0ubuntu2.3), xul-ext-ubufox:amd64 (2.6-0ubuntu0.12.04.1, 2.7-0ubuntu0.12.04.1), libreoffice-style-human:amd64 (4.0.4~rc2-0ubuntu1~precise1, 4.1.0-0ubuntu1~precise1~ppa1), libraptor2-0:amd64 (2.0.6-1, 2.0.6-1ubuntu0.1), grub-pc-bin:amd64 (1.99-21ubuntu3.9, 1.99-21ubuntu3.10), gir1.2-gudev-1.0:amd64 (175-0ubuntu9.3, 175-0ubuntu9.4), vlc:amd64 (2.0.5-0ubuntu0.12.04.1, 2.0.8-0ubuntu0.12.04.1), skype-bin:i386 (4.2.0.11-0ubuntu0.12.04.1, 4.2.0.11-0ubuntu0.12.04.2), libudev0:amd64 (175-0ubuntu9.3, 175-0ubuntu9.4), libudev0:i386 (175-0ubuntu9.3, 175-0ubuntu9.4), jockey-common:amd64 (0.9.7-0ubuntu7.7, 0.9.7-0ubuntu7.9), libisccfg82:amd64 (9.8.1.dfsg.P1-4ubuntu0.6, 9.8.1.dfsg.P1-4ubuntu0.7), gpgv:amd64 (1.4.11-3ubuntu2.2, 1.4.11-3ubuntu2.3), thunderbird-globalmenu:amd64 (17.0.7+build1-0ubuntu0.12.04.1, 17.0.8+build1-0ubuntu0.12.04.1), thunderbird-gnome-support:amd64 (17.0.7+build1-0ubuntu0.12.04.1, 17.0.8+build1-0ubuntu0.12.04.1), jockey-gtk:amd64 (0.9.7-0ubuntu7.7, 0.9.7-0ubuntu7.9), evolution-data-server-common:amd64 (3.2.3-0ubuntu7, 3.2.3-0ubuntu7.1), python-apport:amd64 (2.0.1-0ubuntu17.3, 2.0.1-0ubuntu17.4), evolution-data-server:amd64 (3.2.3-0ubuntu7, 3.2.3-0ubuntu7.1), liblightdm-gobject-1-0:amd64 (1.2.3-0ubuntu2.2, 1.2.3-0ubuntu2.3), vlc-data:amd64 (2.0.5-0ubuntu0.12.04.1, 2.0.8-0ubuntu0.12.04.1), linux-libc-dev:amd64 (3.2.0-49.75, 3.2.0-51.77), grub-common:amd64 (1.99-21ubuntu3.9, 1.99-21ubuntu3.10), grub2-common:amd64 (1.99-21ubuntu3.9, 1.99-21ubuntu3.10), libisc83:amd64 (9.8.1.dfsg.P1-4ubuntu0.6, 9.8.1.dfsg.P1-4ubuntu0.7), libedataserverui-3.0-1:amd64 (3.2.3-0ubuntu7, 3.2.3-0ubuntu7.1), libvlccore5:amd64 (2.0.5-0ubuntu0.12.04.1, 2.0.8-0ubuntu0.12.04.1), libgwibber-gtk2:amd64 (3.4.2-0ubuntu2.2, 3.4.2-0ubuntu2.3), apport-gtk:amd64 (2.0.1-0ubuntu17.3, 2.0.1-0ubuntu17.4), mysql-common:amd64 (5.5.31-0ubuntu0.12.04.2, 5.5.32-0ubuntu0.12.04.1), lsb-release:amd64 (4.0-0ubuntu20.2, 4.0-0ubuntu20.3), thunderbird-locale-en:amd64 (17.0.7+build1-0ubuntu0.12.04.1, 17.0.8+build1-0ubuntu0.12.04.1), python-libxml2:amd64 (2.7.8.dfsg-5.1ubuntu4.4, 2.7.8.dfsg-5.1ubuntu4.6), vlc-plugin-pulse:amd64 (2.0.5-0ubuntu0.12.04.1, 2.0.8-0ubuntu0.12.04.1), gnupg:amd64 (1.4.11-3ubuntu2.2, 1.4.11-3ubuntu2.3)
End-Date: 2013-08-14  08:22:05

Start-Date: 2013-08-14  13:25:30
Commandline: apt-get install curl
Install: curl:amd64 (7.22.0-3ubuntu4.2)
End-Date: 2013-08-14  13:25:38
```

Comment: paste the output of apt-get update on commandline please.

Comment: I have pasted the output of apt-get update above.thanks.

Comment: @liv2shak sorry please also the output of apt-get upgrade we need to check ifcommand line gives more info than the gui. var/log/apt/history.log
 can also be relevant.

Comment: I have added the output of both apt-get upgrade and /var/log/apt/history.log